# Rails - Devise signin(@user) is not working in session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I used a customized controller to do signin as following:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    # super
    @user = User.where(:email => user_params[:email]).first
    if @user.valid_password? user_params[:password]
      sign_in(@user)
      @current_user = @user # even set current user doesn't make sense

      redirect_to '/'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

I also tried using `super`, in database level the user is verified but devise never set session. In both two cases I see record is updated in database:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `current_sign_in_at` = '...', `last_sign_in_at` = '...', `sign_in_count` = .., `updated_at` = '...' WHERE `users`.`id` = 1
```

Comment: Is this function really reachable ? Have you updated the routes for this controller?

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma sure, `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "users/sessions", ... }`.

Comment: Are you sure it's finding the user? Try `find_by_email!(user_params[:email])`

Comment: @MattGibson I think the question is why session is not setting. Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27512278/session-does-not-last-in-rails-4